# Where to store java packages such as jsoup?

Tags: java

I am trying to download jsoup under the following link: https://jsoup.org/download but I am not sure where to save this in my library... Can someone help please!

Comment: In lib directory, or use build and packaging tools like maven or gradle,

Comment: You have to add it to the classpath ;) which IDE do you use ?

Comment: Without more information about your setup, the answer is: Wherever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, things like that come in a JAR file, which is a fancy ZIP file for Java. All your JAR have to listed on the classpath. There are different conventions for where to put your JAR, but, for a simple app, they can be in the root directory of your classes.